# Visualize Space Pascal's triangle

Tags: graphics, visualization

I found this image on the web, and I want to know how to draw it with software.
[image: picture]

I tried to search, and found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9963).

I have learned a mapping in the plane.

Comment: I urge you to include some demonstration of your efforts on this problem.  The community generally reacts negatively to questions that do not demonstrate effort by the author.

Comment: Looking at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77252/turning-pascals-triangle-90-degrees-counter-clockwise) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are a new member I decided to help.

I'll leave it to you to add the joining lines and colors.  Look at [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) for the lines.  Also my use of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) for the numbers means that they do not scale with distance and they are not occluded by the balls.

```
pyr = NestList[ListCorrelate[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}} , #, {-1, 1}, 0] &, {{1}}, 3];

f1[{z_, y_, x_}] := {(x - z/2 + y/2), Sin[60 °] (y - z/3), -z Sin[60 °]}

f2[0, _] := Sequence[]
f2[n_, coor_] := {Sphere[#, 1/4], Text[Style[n, 18], #]} & @ f1[coor]

Graphics3D[
 MapIndexed[f2, pyr, {3}],
 Axes -> True
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to be ornery and render the trinomial tetrahedron upside-down for this answer.

```
segmentList[lst_List, prts_] /; VectorQ[prts, IntegerQ] && Total[prts] == Length[lst] := 
       With[{acc = Accumulate[prts]}, 
            Inner[Take[lst, {#1, #2}] &, Prepend[Most[acc] + 1, 1], acc, List]]

With[{n = 4}, 
     Graphics3D[{Text[Style[#1, Bold, Medium], #2], Sphere[#2, 1/8]} & @@@
                 Flatten[{Table[segmentList[Multinomial @@@ FrobeniusSolve[{1, 1, 1}, k], 
                                            Range[k + 1, 1, -1]], {k, 0, n}], 
                          Table[{{1, 1/2, -1/2},
                                 {0, Sqrt[3]/2, -1/(2 Sqrt[3])},
                                 {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3]}}.{i, j, k},
                                {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, k}, {i, 0, k - j}]},
                         {{4, 3, 2}, {1}}], Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: trinomial tetrahedron]

No lines on this one either; I'll let you figure out how to add them.